# Angular parser called on blur

Tags: angularjs

I have a type of input mask using an angular directive. I'm using a `formatters` and the `blur` event to format the model value for display, and I'm using `parsers` and the `focus` event to remove the formatting when the user edits the textbox.

I'm getting strange behaviour in Internet Explorer where if you use the `Tab` key to lose focus, the parser event is (incorrectly) firing so the model value is being updated incorrectly.

Is this an angular bug? Or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/capesean/htorwgs5/3/

Note that in IE, with your console window open, you will see the events logging out.

Also, testing this on an earlier Angular version, seems to work fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/htorwgs5/4/

The directive code is:

```
.directive("test", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            // for DOM -> model validation
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
                console.log("parser");
                ngModel.$setValidity('test', true);
                return +value;
            });

            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                console.log("formatter");
                ngModel.$setValidity('test', true);
                return (value === undefined ? "" : value) + "!";
            });

            element.val(scope.minutes);

            element.bind("blur", function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    console.log("blur");
                    element.val((scope.minutes === undefined ? "" : scope.minutes) + "@");
                });
            });

            element.bind("focus", function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    console.log("focus");
                    element.val(scope.minutes);
                });
            });

        }
    };
})
```

Comment: both plunkers appear to function the same;  using IE 11 Windows 10.  I'm not seeing what you are describing here.

Comment: @Claies click the input with the "5!" init value, then tab out. The model value (outputted just before the button) turns to NaN. Clicking back into the input, turns the input value to NaN.

Comment: this seems related: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-55.  "ngModel: don't run parsers when executing $validate". You may want to review this change and fix, and see if it is the problem you are having, and potentially if it is still broken.

Comment: also, you didn't mention in your question body which versions of angular you are comparing here;  you merely linked two fiddle links, and in both fiddles, the file `angular.min.js` is used, which doesn't make it easy to determine from the examples which is which, either.....

Answer (score 1):

This is known behaviour. I've posted a bug report here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14987

The solution was to use $timeout to delay the setting of the element value, as suggested in the reply to the bug report.